# Node child of HBox/VBox not following a drag, or moving in a weird way

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

First time asking something here, sorry for my broken English + I'm here because I'm getting upset by my code's behavior, which won't help my english.

Using javaFX (with java only, no FXML) I am trying to make a Node looking like this

[image]

(So multiples HBox in 2 VBox in one HBox) 
And whenever I move it (on Drag), it moves on the screen, but if I use ChangeListener on the child's properties I can see they are not moving at all in reality (layoutX or translateX stay at starting values), which cause me a lot of trouble since I want to connect the nodes's cell (and clicking on things not there is quite the fun).

And when I tried to force it by binding the translateXProperty and all those things my Node's content juste goes away and the code tell me it is where it's supposed to be, but on screen it's juste gone (see pic)

[image]

(There's only an offset on the X value because I used bind() only on translateX to show the problem).
Sorry this is some bad paint right there but I don't know how to show otherwise, and I don't think giving my code would be relevant since I respected the first picture organization. I have tried using Group and Pane and subclasses but it doesn't work, and the HBox + VBox system organize my content just how I want it to be.

I've been looking at the doc and because of my English there must be something I didn't understand at all but well, I don't know, so if you have any idea, if possible where I can keep this organization, thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** 
As some people asked here is what it's looks like in code, with some Listener to see that the content doesn't move, and because I need to be able to make a link between the HBox's circles I need them to have the right translate values.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private double mouseX;
    private double mouseY;
    private double sourceX;
    private double sourceY;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

            @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        HBox root = new HBox(10);

        // Making the first col (see first image)
        VBox left = new VBox(5
                , new HBox(10, new Circle(10, Color.WHEAT), new Rectangle(50, 20, Color.CORAL))
                , new HBox(10, new Circle(10, Color.WHEAT), new Rectangle(50, 20, Color.CORAL))
        );

        // Making the second col (see first image)

        VBox right = new VBox(5);
        right.translateXProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("right VBox " +
                "translate to " + newValue)); // Isn't called
        root.getChildren().add(right);

        // Making the first row of the right col (see first image)
        HBox row0Right = new HBox(10);
        row0Right.translateXProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("row0Right " +
                "HBox translate to " + newValue)); // Isn't called
        row0Right.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(50, 20, Color.CYAN));
        // Making a Circle with a translate Listener
        Circle circle = new Circle(10, Color.CRIMSON);
        circle.translateXProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("circle " +
                "row0col1 translate to " + newValue)); // Isn't called
        row0Right.getChildren().add(circle);

        // Making the second row of the right col (see first image)
        HBox row1Right = new HBox(10);
        row1Right.translateXProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("row1Right " +
                "HBox translate to " + newValue)); // Isn't called
        row1Right.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(50, 20, Color.CYAN));
        row1Right.getChildren().add(new Circle(10, Color.CRIMSON));
        right.getChildren().addAll(row0Right, row1Right);

        root.setOnMousePressed(event ->
        {
            mouseX = event.getSceneX();
            mouseY = event.getSceneY();
            sourceX = ((Node) (event.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            sourceY = ((Node) (event.getSource())).getTranslateY();
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(event ->
        {
            double newX = sourceX + event.getSceneX() - mouseX;
            double newY = sourceY + event.getSceneY() - mouseY;
            ((Node) (event.getSource())).setTranslateX(newX);
            ((Node) (event.getSource())).setTranslateY(newY);
        });

        root.translateXProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("root translate " +
                "to " + newValue)); // Is the only one called

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 720, 720));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**
I noticed that if I use a Rectangle as the moving root, and bind shapes translates to it, everything is fine, but I prefer the way the HBox/VBox place the children as I don't want to set every single px in x, y, width and height for every shapes bind to my core rectangle (which might become a lot of shapes) when I can use those Box pattern.

Comment: I think posting [mcve] of the problem would have been more effective than describing the code.

Comment: Are you dragging the node between windows? Did you take into account that there may be multiple ancestors with a position != `(0, 0)` that all contribute to the position of the node in the common ancestor. BTW: without a [mcve] this question is not answerable.